# Does gorm support multiple indexes on same field?

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

```
type ABCUser struct {
    ID    uint   `json:"id" gorm:"primary_key" `
    Name  string `json:"name" gorm:"index:name_filter"`
    Age   string `json:"foreign_name" gorm:"index:age_filter"`
    Place string `json:"node_id" gorm:"index:place_filter"`
    Class string `gorm:"index:name_filter;index:age_filter;index:place_filter"`
}

//calling migration like 
db.AutoMigrate(&ABCUser{})
```

gorm logs (added comments after // by me)

```
[2021-03-02 17:21:10]  [16.73ms]  CREATE TABLE `abc_users` (`id` int unsigned AUTO_INCREMENT,`name` varchar(255),`age` varchar(255),`place` varchar(255),`class` varchar(255) , PRIMARY KEY (`id`))  
[0 rows affected or returned ] 

[2021-03-02 17:21:10]  [13.97ms]  CREATE INDEX name_filter ON `abc_users`(`name`)   
[0 rows affected or returned ] 

[2021-03-02 17:21:11]  [17.93ms]  CREATE INDEX age_filter ON `abc_users`(`age`)   
[0 rows affected or returned ] // not expected want `abc_users`(`age`, `class`)   

[2021-03-02 17:21:11]  [11.80ms]  CREATE INDEX place_filter ON `abc_users`(`place`, `class`)   
[0 rows affected or returned ] // not expected want `abc_users`(`place`, `class`)
PASS
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this out of scope of gorm?

Comment: In the `Class` field, you define  three index but two names already exists (age_filter and place_filter ) so try renaming them

Comment: You got the index you wanted (`abc_users(place, class)`) in the last line. The age_filter index not being on `(age, class)` seems like a bug, and something you probably want to file in the [gorm issue tracker](https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/issues).

Answer (score 1):

I use with ";" separating the indexes
Like this example

```
field string `gorm:"index:idx_field;index:idx_table_unique,unique"`
```